# What is the output of this regex

Tags: regex

What is the output of this regular expression?

```
/\s+(\d+)\s+/
```

In particular what is the meaning of /\s

Comment: Why don't you run it and see what the output is?

Answer (score 0):

In your regex `\s+` matches any number of whitespaces sequentially and `/d+` matches any number of digits sequentially .

`\s` and `\d` matches a single whitespace and single digit respectively the `+` makes it match any number of sequential whitespaces and digits respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a full explanation at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ABJEVa/1).

```
/\s+(\d+)\s+/

\s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

1st Capturing Group (\d+)

\d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])

+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

\s+ matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

+ Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/

might be useful :D

> \s+(\d+)\s+ / ↵ matches the character
>    ↵ literally (case sensitive) 
>   \s+
>   matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>   + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 1st Capturing Group 
>   (\d+)
>   \d+ matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
>   + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
>   \s+ matches any whitespace
>   character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])
>   + Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed